# Rank Date based on today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple date dimension,

```
SELECT [actualDate]
FROM (
    VALUES ('2021-09-20')
    ,      ('2021-09-21')
    ,      ('2021-09-22')
    ,      ('2021-09-23')
    ,      ('2021-09-24')
    ,      ('2021-09-25')
    ,      ('2021-09-26')
    ,      ('2021-09-27')
    ,      ('2021-09-28')
) as t(actualDate)
```

I'm attempting to write a Window function (without much luck..) to net the following result.

where 1 is today and 0 is yesterday.

```
+----------+----------+
|actualDate|dateOffset|
+----------+----------+
|2021-09-20|-4        |
|2021-09-21|-3        |
|2021-09-22|-2        |
|2021-09-23|-1        |
|2021-09-24|0         |
|2021-09-25|1         |
|2021-09-26|2         |
|2021-09-27|3         |
|2021-09-28|4         |
+----------+----------+
```

What can I try next? I'm unsure what to search for.

Comment: thanks @DaleK I had a page of scripts with my own attempts with lots of hacky case statements - I didn't want to bias the question or clutter it up with my badly written attempt hence I left it out. I did read a lot (I spent an hour looking) for solutions but felt like I was looking at the question incorrectly so left it out.  Understand this is against the mcve guidance and accept any downvotes as a consequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the dates are continuous, we don't even need analytic functions but instead we can just use `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT
    actualDate,
    1 + DATEDIFF(day, CAST(GETDATE() AS date), actualDate) dateOffset
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY actualDate;
```

### Demo